# How do I look into a specific OU when I am using msolservice

Tags: powershell, azure

I am using `MsolService` in PowerShell to export data from the AD but I need to look into a specific OU (organizational unit) and download just the records in there.

What should I be doing here in order to do that ?

I am just using a basic command to get an export of licensed users which is

```
Connect-MsolService
Get-MsolUser -All | Where-Object {$_.isLicensed -eq "TRUE"} | Export-Csv path
```

Now how do I make this search not look into the root but a specific organizational unit which would be a folder in the AD

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your code so we can see what you are doing? `Connect-MsolService` is normally only one part of a script.

Comment: I am looking for something equivalent to Searchbase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for Get-​Msol​User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/get-msoluser?view=azureadps-1.0) shows that there is no option for filtering by OU. Instead you will need to filter the users using `Get-ADUser` with the `SearchBase` parameter, and then call `Get-​Msol​User` on each of the results:

```
$Users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Accounts,DC=Domain,DC=com" -Filter *

foreach ($User in $Users) {
    Get-​Msol​User -UserPrincipalName $User.userprincipalname | Where-Object {$_.isLicensed -eq "TRUE"} | Export-Csv $path -Append
}
```

*Note: This is untested as I don't have an AD connection at present.*